# excel file data into datatable

Tags: c#, excel, ole

i am using the code below to select all of the data from a excel file and was wondering if it would be possible for me to start from row three and read in the rest of the data within the file..

```
excelConnectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
            // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
            using (OleDbConnection excelConnection =
                new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {                    
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string[] excelSheet = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int sheet = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheet[sheet] = row["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        sheet++;

                    }
                    excelDataTable.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < excelSheet.Length; i++)
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                             ("Select  * FROM [" + excelSheet[i] + "]", excelConnection);

                        excelAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                        excelAdapter.Fill(excelDataTable);
                    }
                    excelConnection.Close();
                }

            return excelDataTable;
```

Comment: Are there Headers in the file?

Comment: no.. but they are dat that has to be used later for other aspects

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to ammend your file before reading in with Oledbconnection :-

```
private string customiseTemplate(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create Instance of Excel Appllication
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            //Create a WorkBook Object.
            Workbooks wbks = app.Workbooks;

            //Populate Workbook from Excel File.
            _Workbook _wbk = wbks.Add(filename);

            //Create Sheet Object.
            Sheets shs = _wbk.Sheets;

            //Determine which sheet to work with. In this instance there should only ever be one. 
            _Worksheet _wsh = (_Worksheet)shs.get_Item(1);



            //Delete Unwanted Rows 1 to 3.

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
            range1 = (Range)_wsh.get_Range("A1:A3", Missing.Value);

            range1.EntireRow.Delete(Missing.Value);

            // Release Range
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range1);

            //Save WorkBook.

            app.AlertBeforeOverwriting = false;

            string newFile = filename.Insert(3, "Ammended_");

            _wbk.SaveAs(newFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            // CLose Excel App.
            app.Quit();

            // Release unnecessary excel processes
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            app = null;

            return newFile;

        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: i dont wnat to delete the rows because the needed

Comment: What are they needed for if you dont want them in your DataTable?

Comment: You could always read the data in, and then remove those three rows from your DataTable. Table.Rows[0].Delete(); The example above is saving a new file, its not replacing the old one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As I think it needs t be clear. Are you saying sometimes you need the forst three rows reading, and other times not?

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = sqlData.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>("slideNo") == "5")
                .Select(data=> data.Field<String>("QuestionStartText"));
```

this is the answer for the coding...

Answer (score 0):

Derek is right, I agree with him. If you still want to keep the original excel file data and show only a part in your datatable, you need to first export total excel data to datatable, and then, delete rows you do not need in datatable. If you does not need the rows, you can first delete the rows you do not want in original excel file and then,export excel to datatable.